# How To Enable Debug Mode From ADB Shell or ADB Via Terminal In Linux

Tags: adb, linux, shell, terminal, debug

so far I have put my android device in ftm mode
i have tried from `adb sideload`
now i am trying with `busybox ash`

I'm able to run  `ls`
but anything else says permission denied or error:closed.

```
/ $ ls
acct
cache
charger
config
d
data
default.prop
dev
etc
file_contexts
firmware
fstab.qcom
icon_ftm.png
init
init.class_main.sh
init.environ.rc
init.ftm.rc
init.mdm.sh
init.offcharge.rc
init.qcom.bms.sh
init.qcom.class_core.sh
init.qcom.early_boot.sh
init.qcom.factory.rc
init.qcom.ftm.rc
init.qcom.rc
init.qcom.sh
init.qcom.syspart_fixup.sh
init.qcom.usb.rc
init.qcom.usb.sh
init.rc
init.target.ftm.rc
init.target.rc
init.trace.rc
init.usb.rc
init.vendor.rc
init.zygote32.rc
mnt
persist
proc
property_contexts
res
root
sbin
sdcard
seapp_contexts
selinux_version
sepolicy
service_contexts
storage
sys
system
tombstones
ueventd.qcom.rc
ueventd.rc
vendor
verity_key
```

Comment: I want to chmod on root folder

Comment: and also unlock the bootloader and root the phone

Comment: Insufficient information. Not clear what you are asking. By **Debug Mode** do you mean USB Debugging? What is ***anything else*** which gives permission denied?

Comment: Further: of course you get a permission denied. Line 1 of your quote shows the reason. Hint: `$` is not `#`. And indeed the question sounds like chicken-and-egg: "enable debugging from ADB" is like "switching on the lights of a burning lamp". So you need to be clearer on what you're asking.

Comment: @antoinepl514 never chmod or chown anything, android is not like linux it will crash if something unexpected. for unlocking/rooting you don't need adb or (root) shell running on device. for unlocking use fastboot (not adb). rooting usually can be done offline, patch your boot/recovery and flash it back

Comment: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#boot-image-patching

Comment: alright,  I will try that , thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** make use of ADB without turning on the Debugging mode. There is one way to access partitions via ADB even if you don't have ADB turned on. If you want to run **ls** on restricted partitions, like **cd data**, you need to boot (not flash) into a custom recovery. Asssuming that you have an unlocked device, run `fastboot boot <recovery.img>`.
Now that you have successfully booted into a custom recovery, **mount** relevant partitions and run adb commands.

Comment: OP says: ***“I want to chmod on root folder and also unlock the bootloader and root the phone”***.

Comment: We don't usually perform chmod on Android. As @alecxs has mentioned, chmod may have unexpected behaviour on an Android. Try running `adb remount` followed by `adb root`.

Comment: OP says: “I want to chmod on root folder and also **unlock the bootloader** and root the phone”. And you suggest: “Asssuming that you have an unlocked device...”. And I do `chmod` scores of times on my device in a day, the point is you should know what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, because you can't perform these operations on a production build. You need to have **root permissions** for which you need to run **adb root**. And for that you need to have a **custom recovery or root privileges**, and for that you need an **unlocked bootloader**.

Comment: it seems that I cannot find the custom recovery or custom rom files nowhere for the ZTE Avid Plus Z828

Comment: Yes, I was looking for resources for ZTE Avid Plus Z828 and I barely found anything at all.  Only if you can manage rooting your phone manually, you should be able to workaround other problems.